# Magento2: JS Translations not working

Tags: magento2, knockoutjs

On my Magento version 2.1.4, I have added language file nl_NL.csv under app/design/frontend/Vendor/Themename/i18n folder. It's working fine for strings added in php code like this

But the translations not showing for string added in KO JS like this

Can anyone tell me what could be the issue? OR how can I create js translations?
I understand there is a file js-translation.json generated in pub/static/frontend/Hyp/deboomhut/nl_NL directory which is responsible for js translations. But don't know how it's generated and from where it pulls the tralsations. So any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Remove /var/view_processed directory.

Delete file **pub/static/frontend/Hyp/deboomhut/nl_NL/js-translations.json** file.

Deploy static content.
After that visit website in browser with Ctrl+F5.

If still now work then open file **js-translations.json** in browser with Ctrl+F5.

And then visit website.

Comment: I've tried these steps but didn't worked. Do you mean Ctrl+F5 here? I tried everything but still not working.

Comment: In browser js-translation.json file display content. www.domain.com/pub/static/frontend/Hyp/deboomhut/nl_NL/js-translations.json check with Alt+F5 check there any data display here

Comment: js-translation.json has some translations. But not all like in minicart "http://prntscr.com/et13e6". Don't know why all translations not present there. How can I add these translations to that file?

Comment: You have to check from where this text come there is js translation used properly or manually you can add translation in this file

Comment: That is what I'm asking, from where this file js-translations.json collects the translations?